PyQt5 - приложение 'не отвечает', при запуске иного процесса из другого файла
часть кода:
class AutoAdditionProfilesWindow(QWidget):
def __init__(self, main_window=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle("Create Profile")
    self.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 100)

    self.layout = QFormLayout()
    self.setLayout(self.layout)

    self.cookies_input = QPushButton("Choose Files")
    self.cookies_input.clicked.connect(self.choose_cookies_files)
    self.layout.addRow(QLabel("Choose Files:"), self.cookies_input)

    self.save_button = QPushButton("start")
    self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.start)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.save_button)

    self.file_path = "./files/profiles_info.json"

def choose_cookies_files(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    self.files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Select Cookies Files", "", "Text Files (*.txt);;All Files (*)", options=options)
    if self.files: 
        self.cookies_input.setText(f"{len(self.files)}")

def start(self):

    ##=============================================##
    ##=============================================##
    

    from find_auth_keys import find_keys

    self.list_of_tokens = ["a375a9d14d00431052b4d668d7501d7fa243fce3"]

    text = QLabel("finding keys.")
    self.layout.addWidget(text)

    self.progress = QProgressBar()
    self.progress.setVisible(True)
    self.progress.setMaximum(len(self.files))
    self.layout.addWidget(self.progress)

    self.progress.setValue(self.progress.value() + 1)
    for index, path in enumerate(self.files):
        self.progress.setValue(self.progress.value() + 1)
        
        keys = find_keys(path, self)

        for key in keys:
            self.list_of_tokens.append(key)

    ##=============================================##
    ##=============================================##

    text.setText("checking profiles.")
    self.layout.removeWidget(self.progress)
    self.progress.deleteLater()

    self.progress = QProgressBar()
    self.progress.setVisible(True)
    self.progress.setMaximum(len(self.list_of_tokens))
    self.layout.addWidget(self.progress)

    self.progress.setValue(self.progress.value() + 1)

    chunk_size = 6
    profiles_queue = [self.list_of_tokens[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(self.list_of_tokens), chunk_size)]

    try:
        for profile in profiles_queue:
            from main_module import Application

            Application([], {}).check_cookies([profile], self)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    print(self.list_of_tokens)


    ##=============================================##
    ##=============================================##

    text.setText("adding profiles.")
    self.layout.removeWidget(self.progress)
    self.progress.deleteLater()

    self.progress = QProgressBar()
    self.progress.setVisible(True)
    self.progress.setMaximum(len(self.list_of_tokens))
    self.layout.addWidget(self.progress)

    self.progress.setValue(self.progress.value() + 1)
    for key in self.list_of_tokens:
        unique_code = self.generate_unique_code()
        profile_key = f"profile_{unique_code}"

        profile_data = {
            "name": profile_key,
            "cookies": {"name": "auth_token", "value": f"{key}", "path": "/", "domain": ".x.com"},
            "proxy": "",
            "notes": "",
            "tags": ""
        }

        with open(self.file_path, 'r') as file:
            data = json.load(file)

        data[profile_key] = profile_data

        with open(self.file_path, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
            json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
        
        self.progress.setValue(self.progress.value() + 1)

def generate_unique_code(self):
    return str(uuid.uuid4())

как сказал ранее, программа "не отвечает", (как я понимаю) когда запускается процесс с другого файла. А мне важно, как минимум, сделать прогрес бар.
пробовал оптимизировать - не помогло

На сколько я понял, под понятием "не отвечает", вы имели ввиду ситуацию когда приложение застывает, при открытии другого qt апликейшена? Правильно?

Ещё один из симптомов, при закрытии второго апликейшена, первый продолжает работать как ничего не было?

не совсем. Оно это делает при, как я понял, запуске других функций из других файлов. По типу find_keys и Application([], {}).check_cookies([profile], self). Она именно "не отвечает", винда так и пишет.
Так же, после того, как эти процессы (check_cookies или же find_keys) заканчивают свою работу - UI тут же начинает работать и отвечать на разные действия

Ваши функции вытесняют приложение qt из главного потока, как вариант можно запустить эти функции в побочном потоке при помощи multithreading

Вот ещё только что нашел, более корректный вариант использовать QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents(). Проверил, будто бы работает @Duxtaa

Документация более многословна чем я)

Решение нашлось и очень даже простое. Спасибо Justiks.
добавил QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents() в for-циклы, и проблема пропала.
пример:
for profile in profiles_queue:
    from main_module import Application

    Application([], {}).check_cookies([profile], self)
    self.progress.setValue(self.progress.value() + 1)
    QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()

импорт:
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

ещё раз спасибо автору Justiks!☺️

Рад был помочь!
